# Google Cloud Platform: Pub/Sub to Bigtable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-bigtable

I am building a pipeline on Google Cloud Platform in Python. I have my data in Cloud Pub/Sub. I want to store it into Bigtable by using Dataflow. So far I have some examples of streaming data from Pub/Sub to Bigtable in java.

Can anyone please help me with some resources or links on how to stream my data from Pub/Sub to Bigtable using Dataflow in Python?

Answer (score 4):

Sam, 
I am not sure how we do this in Python. But I have done this in Java. Hope the idea may help you to solve your problem.

steps that you should keep in mind while doing this are

1. Read from Pub/Sub, Set the streaming to true

   ```
   PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION))
   ```
2. Group the collection with a constant key

   ```
   PCollection<KV<String, String>> keyedStream = streamData
           .apply(WithKeys.of(new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
               /**
                * serial version id
                */
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               public String apply(String s) {
                   return CONSTANT_KEY;
               }
           }));
   ```
3. A transform is created for dividing the elements in the `PCollection` into windows and trigger the control when those elements are output.

   ```
   Window.<String>into(new GlobalWindows())
           .triggering(Repeatedly
                   .forever(AfterProcessingTime
                           .pastFirstElementInPane()
                           .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
                       )).withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(1)).discardingFiredPanes()
   ```
4. Write the `PCollection` to Bigtable.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for giving a brief idea. I am working on the solution in python and will post it here soon.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to help you on the steps that would need to follow. Because, it took a day for me to implement.

Comment: I am not sure that this is currently possible in Python.
There is no source/sink in Apache Beam (as of 2.1.0 nor in the upcoming 2.2.0) that supports BigTable unlike the existing support in the Java version of the SDK.

Comment: @Sam - Were you able to work on the solution in Python?