# Sink all projects under an organisation into a bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, google-logging

I am building a similar approach to bring all the logs into BigQuery dataset. As per this https://dev.to/alvardev/gcp-cloud-logging-the-basis-45eh I am able to bring the project log details into the corresponding BigQuery. But how do we bring all the projects logs into a single Bigtable i.e for example lets say An organisation has 50 projects and with minimal configuration I want all the logs from 50 projects to come under a single Bigtable as consolidated project logs.

Is this possible in GCP, can someone please help me on this

[image]

Comment: @MabelA. provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only supported destinations based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks#supported-destinations) are Cloud Storage, Pub/Sub, BigQuery and another Cloud Logging Bucket . However I found this another approach where the architecture is: Cloud Logging -> Pub/Sub -> [DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow) -> [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java#writing).

Basically, you will [create a sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks#create_an_aggregated_sink) and choose Pub/Sub topic as the destination then from there, you can stream your data from Pub/Sub to Bigtable using Dataflow. You can check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831948/16531441) that you can use as reference on how to stream data from Pub/Sub to BT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also I would like to know if it possible to transfer Bigtable to BigQuery. i.e lets say I want all data greater than 1 year should be moved from Datatable to BigQuery. Is this doable?

Comment: @AlexMan here's a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable) on how to query Bigtable data on BigQuery. If you need a detailed answer, please post a new question so other people can contribute.

Comment: I have created an [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507851/gcp-moving-bigtable-data-to-bigquery) for this