# GCP moving Bigtable data to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigtable

In GCP I would like to know if it possible to transfer/move data from Bigtable to BigQuery. i.e lets say I want all data greater than 1 year should be moved from Bigtable to BigQuery. Is this doable?

Can someone please help me on this

Comment: As it has been a few years, is there still no GCP native way of replicating OLTP transactional data from BigTable to Analytics BigQuery store?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the BigTable data from BigQuery thanks to the [external table configuration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#bq).

Because you are able to query the data from BigQuery, you can perform an INSERT SELECT in a BigQuery table.

---

**EDIT 1**

You can't do it automatically. You must perform custom code to copy only the old data and then delete the old ones.

You must have a timestamp field for that. To copy the data from BigTable to BigQuery, you can use external table. But you can't delete the data from BigQuery external connection.

To purge BigTable data, you can use [garbage collection](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/garbage-collection) feature.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot delete data from Bigtable.....Does this a normal behaviour in GCP Bigtable that we cannot delete data

Comment: No, no, I made a mistake between BigTable and BigQuery. You can't delete data from BigQuery  external connection, it's read only. You have to use BigTable feature to update/delete BigTable data.